# React-native application hanging when updating a parent from a child

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks

I've a weird behavior here.

I'm trying to update a parent component from a child.

I've thus something like this for the child:

```js
const LabelList = ({editable, boardLabels, cardLabels, size='normal', udpateCardLabelsHandler}) => {
     return (
            <DropDownPicker
                labelStyle={{
                    fontWeight: "bold"
                  }}
                badgeColors={badgeColors}
                showBadgeDot={false}
                items={items}
                multiple={true}
                open={open}
                onChangeValue={(value) => udpateCardLabelsHandler(value)}
                value={value}
                setOpen={setOpen}
                setValue={setValue} />
        )
}
```

And, for the parent, something like this:

```js
const CardDetails = () => {
    const [updatedCardLabels, setUpdatedCardLabels] = useState([])
    const [card, setCard] = useState({})
    const [editMode, setEditMode] = useState(false)

    // Handler to let the LabelList child update the card's labels
    const udpateCardLabelsHandler = (values) => {
        const boardLabels = boards.value[route.params.boardId].labels
        const labels = boardLabels.filter(label => {
            return values.indexOf(label.id) !== -1
        })    
        console.log('updated labels',labels)
        setUpdatedCardLabels(labels)
    }

    return (
        <View style={{zIndex: 10000}}>
              <Text h1 h1Style={theme.title}>
                   {i18n.t('labels')}
              </Text>
              <LabelList 
                    editable = {editMode}
                    boardLabels = {boards.value[route.params.boardId].labels}
                    cardLabels = {card.labels}
                    udpateCardLabelsHandler = {udpateCardLabelsHandler} />
            </View>
     )
```

And, this just doesn't work: As soon as I try changing something in the DropDownPicker the application hangs. The `console.log` statement isn't even executed and no errors show up in my expo console.

What's strange is that if I change the `updateCardLabels` state to be a boolean for example, everything works ok (eg: the `console.log` statement is executed):

```js
const [updatedCardLabels, setUpdatedCardLabels] = useState(false)

// Handler to let the LabelList child update the card's labels
const udpateCardLabelsHandler = (values) => {
    const boardLabels = boards.value[route.params.boardId].labels
    const labels = boardLabels.filter(label => {
        return values.indexOf(label.id) !== -1
    })    
    console.log('updated labels',labels)
    setUpdatedCardLabels(true)
}
```

Please note that `updatedCardLabels` isn't used anywhere: it's a dummy variable that I'm just using to debug this issue (to make sure I was not ending in some endless render loop or something similar).

For the sake of completeness, here's what `labels` looks like at line `console.log('updated labels',labels)` (please not that I can only see this value when doing `setUpdatedCardLabels(true)` as otherwise, when the code does `setUpdatedCardLabels(labels)`, the console.log statement is not executed, as mentioned earlier):

```
updated labels Array [
  Object {
    "ETag": "a95b2566521a73c5edfb7b8f215948bf",
    "boardId": 1,
    "cardId": null,
    "color": "CC317C",
    "id": 9,
    "lastModified": 1621108392,
    "title": "test-label",
  },
]
```

Does anybody have an explanation for this strange behavior?

Best regards,

Cyrille

Comment: What debugging other than changing the `updatedCardLabels` value to a boolean have you done? Are there any errors? A cod estacktrace? Where is `updatedCardLabels` state used/referenced? It seems `udpateCardLabelsHandler` takes a `values` argument, but your code passes a `value` value in `DropDownPicker`. What is the value of `values` in `udpateCardLabelsHandler` handler? Have you stepped through the `udpateCardLabelsHandler` to see where it breaks?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your feedback.

I've updated my question to answer yours but here's the summary: 

There's no single error showing up in my expo console and `updatedCardLabels` is not used anywhere: It's a dummy variable I've created to debug this issue (to make sure I was not ending in some endless render loop or something similar).

I can't step through `updateCardLabelsHandler`: even if I put a `console.log` statement at its very first line, it isn't executed when `setUpdatedCardLabels` gets an array as argument.

Comment: So just changing `setUpdatedCardLabels(labels)` to `setUpdatedCardLabels(true)` allows the code to work? Does the code work without issue if you remove this line entirely? Seems it's not serving any useful purpose considering you say you aren't using `updatedCardLabels` state value anywhere.

Comment: well, `updatedCardLabels` will be used eventualy after I figure out how to update it...

Comment: You should be able to update it to whatever you want. Is something referencing it now, which causes error if it's an array?

Answer (score 0):

So, I've found the problem: It was a side effect of the DrowpDownPicker.

I've solved it by changing my child as follow:

```
const LabelList = ({editable, boardLabels, cardLabels, size='normal', udpateCardLabelsHandler}) => {

    const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
    const [value, setValue] = useState(cardLabels.map(item => item.id));

    const theme = useSelector(state => state.theme)

    // Updates parent when value changes
    useEffect(() => {
        if (typeof udpateCardLabelsHandler !== 'undefined') {
            udpateCardLabelsHandler(value)
        }
    }, [value])

        return (
            <DropDownPicker
                labelStyle={{
                    fontWeight: "bold"
                  }}
                badgeColors={badgeColors}
                showBadgeDot={false}
                items={items}
                multiple={true}
                open={open}
                value={value}
                setOpen={setOpen}
                setValue={setValue} />
        )
```